# how to fetch ip address in JMeter remote testing

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, ip-address, load-testing, distributed-testing

I'm trying to load test with 3 remote servers, after test ends all the requests are shown in result tree, but I cannot find out which ip address (remote server) sent the request.

for example if I send one request from each remote server, then I see three total request in result tree, but I cannot understand which is for which

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) functions as prefix or postfix for your [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) labels - this way you will be able to distinguish the results coming from different remote slaves.

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.

Comment: @should I disable calling this function in real test? Does it have any performance issue?

Comment: You can create an [User Defined Variable](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) at the beginning of the test so the function will be called only once. The function of course has its cost but it doesn't do any intensive computing so the overhead will be minimal